# Facebook android sdk's Session.requestNewPublishPermissions gives an exception

Tags: android, facebook, integration, android-facebook

I'm integrating facebook into my android application, when user has logged in for first time, I'm requesting publish_actions permissions using my requestFacebookPermissions(session) method. but whenever I call this method it gives me below exception...

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
```

I don't have any other request pending, might be some other internal request but How do I request permissions without getting this exception? it is ok if I have to wait till other requests are completed, but I don't know how to get whether pending requests are completed.

```
private void requestFacebookPermissions(Session session) {

        if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()) {
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

            Log.i("Facebook", "Permissions Count: " + permissions.size());

            for (String string : permissions) {
                Log.i("FacebookPermissions", string);
            }

            if (!permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
                try {
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FacebookActivity.this, PERMISSIONS));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ask for publish permission after log-in

This is my code

```
public class FacebookAccount extends FragmentActivity {
    private UserSettingsFragment userSettingsFragment;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        userSettingsFragment = (UserSettingsFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.login_fragment);

        userSettingsFragment.setReadPermissions(Utility.READ_PERMISSIONS);

        userSettingsFragment
                .setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        if (state == SessionState.OPENED
                                && !session.getPermissions().containsAll(
                                        Utility.PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS)) {
                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                    FacebookAccount.this,
                                    Utility.PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS));
                        }
                        if (session.isOpened()
                                && state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
                            ....Save session access token
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (userSettingsFragment != null)
            userSettingsFragment
                    .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```